# Symfony2 cssrewrite filter's image paths are way off

Tags: jquery-ui, symfony, assetic

I'm trying to get Symfony2 to work with jQuery UI. I've gotten the JavaScript portion of it working just fine but I'm having trouble getting the images to work.

One thing I read in the Assetic docs is that the `cssrewrite` filter can take the image paths in CSS files and update them so the paths point to the right places. This looked like exactly what I needed, so I enabled `cssrewrite`. Here's how `cssrewrite` changed my paths:

```
// original
images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png

// using cssrewrite
../../../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png
```

The first path is no good. The `cssrewrite` path at least points to the correct path in the filesystem, but relative to my webroot, the `cssrewrite` path is WAY off. Obviously my `app` directory is not public.

How do I get the `cssrewrite` filter to change my paths to something that will actually work?

Here's my stylesheet inclusion. (And yes, I know that the way I'm individually including all these CSS files is dumb, but I'm not worried about that right now.)

```
    {% stylesheets
        '../app/Resources/public/css/*'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.progressbar.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css'
        '../app/Resources/public/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: See the answer to my question, it has a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony2

Answer (score 11):

There are some [known problems](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/53) with the CssRewrite filter. For what I know, it does not work properly by using the `@BundleName` notation and a workaround seems to be linking the CSS files by using the `bundles/bundle_name` path.

Thus your code should be something like this:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' 
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/*'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.accordion.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.base.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.button.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.resizable.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.selectable.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.slider.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.tabs.css'
        'bundles/<your_bundle_name>/css/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css'
    %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
```

Where `<your_bundle_name>` is obviously the name of the bundle you are working on.

**EDIT:** remember to give the `php app/console assets:install --symlink web` command, in order to symbolically link your assets into the `web` directory.