# Symfony2, where to put css, javascript, images

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm a beginner at Symfony2, and I have some problems about putting resource like css, js, images...
I just read this document [how to use Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html)
But I can't figure out what is the best way to put my assets. That article show me that I should put js files inside my Bundle, but put css files in /web/public/css (out side the Bundle). That's complicated and inconvenience.
Can somebody show me ?
Thanks

Comment: See excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony2.  This has worked well for us.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can put them into the *Bundle/Resources/public/, then run

> $ php app/console assets:install --symlink

This will create a symbolic link with the bundle name in your web/bundles/ linking to the existing bundles' public folders. If you want a simpler path in your html (or mainly css) code you can create a symbolic link directly in your web folder.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the Accepted Answer

```
app/console assets:install web --symlink
```

When you include your files (css,js,image) you need to change the PATH like that in **TWIG** :

```
{{ asset('bundles/myBundle/css/main.css') }}
```

And in **PHP** :

```
<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('bundles/myBundle/img/logo.png') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We put them in web/assets/[css|img|js|fonts|less|xml|...]

Answer (score 0):

If your css/js file is used only within your bundle, placing them in bundle resources is OK. Otherwise placing onto the public folder if it's used by many bundles