# Symfony2 Assetic Image Path

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm new to Symfony and I'm trying to include and image (stored in the bundle Resources/public/images dir) in a twig template. When I render the page however the img tag has a non existent src path. I'm not sure what is going on, any advice would be appreciated greatly.

My Twig File

```
{% image '@XYZTestBundle/Resources/public/images/bananas.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Symfony!" />
{% endimage %}
```

The rendered image tag

```
<img src="/myproject/web/images/5fcddd8.jpg" alt="Symfony!">
```

There are no files in the /myproject/web/images/ directory

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found my answer here. I hope this helps someone else in the future

https://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle/issues/41

Comment: Make sure that you accept this when the system allows you too.

Answer (score 0):

have you try the command php app/console assetic:dump or php app/console assets:install ?

otherwise I think this link can help you : 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html

Answer (score 0):

As Tali says, you should execute the command "assetic:dump" to dump your bundle assets in web folder.