# Symfony Assetic is not linking own bundles

Tags: php, symfony, assetic, php-5.6

I found something that I can't explain why symfony behaves like this.
I created several bundles to brake down the funktionality of my script to modules.
Everything works fine so far.
Today I deployed it for the first time to an staging environment.
I executed

php app/console assetic:dump

without any issues.
I then executes

php app/console assets:install web

but it didn't create symlinks for my own bundles. (Own my dev system they are there).

Here's the output:

```
php app/console assets:install
Installing assets as hard copies.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
Installing assets for Stfalcon\Bundle\TinymceBundle into web/bundles/stfalcontinymce
Installing assets for JMS\JobQueueBundle into web/bundles/jmsjobqueue
```

None of my bundles appear here.
I am wondering how I can enable this, because I need to push also several images that belong to bundles with it.

I created the bundles using

php app/console generate:bundle

and controller skeletons

php app/console generate:controller

I did not modify any of the structure.
(I am using anotation in the controller files and yml as config files)
What am I missing?
Didn't really have any look on searching in google as I don't really know where the problems are coming from.
Or is it even an problem?
Are there any folders missing?

Comment: have you added your bundles into config.yml under assetic:bundles:[] ?

Comment: Yes I did. This is the line: bundles:        [UserBundle,HomeBundle,AdminBundle]

Comment: But I don't know why it is not working. Is there a chance that I need to have certain folders that it works?

Comment: Are your assets in Bundle/Resources/assets and/or Bundle/Resources/public? (btw, you are installing your assets as hard copies, for symlinks you have to use  'assets:install --symlink'.)

Comment: ok, that explains some things. I had them under Resources but not under public or assets.

Comment: I moved them and it worked. thx

Comment: Please post your comment as Answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bundles need to be added into

```
assetic:
    bundles:[yourBundle]
```

assetic expects your files in

```
Bundle/Resources/assets
```

and/or

```
Bundle/Resources/public
```

folders.

(I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony-2/10290213#10290213) before a while, maybe it can be usefull to you to..)