# Symfony 2 route for static resources (js, css ...)

Tags: javascript, css, symfony

I use Symfony 2.7 with the internal web server (installed with composer).
I want to use different resources (css, js, images, fonts) in my twig files with a path like this

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

In this case I get an error message: No route found for "GET /css/style.css"

I copied the resources to the web folder /web/css etc. so the files should be in the right place.
How can I configure the routing that it picks up the resources without an error?

Thanks

Bernhard

Comment: Take a look at this [chapter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#linking-to-assets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with

```
<link href="{{ asset('/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that fixed it, just one more question: Within a css I have something like that:

`background-image:url(/images/icons/loader.gif)` 

How can I handle this links in the stylesheet?

Comment: I suggest you to read this question, very long but usefull : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony-2

Answer (score 0):

In your `base.html.twig`, you should add this:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
```