# CSS image path missing using assetic in symfony2

Tags: html, css, symfony, assetic

I'm trying to follow Symfony best practices with keeping general assets stored directly in the /web root. I am trying to set a background image in css which is not loading.

Folder Structure.

- web

  - assets

    - css

      - style.css
    - images

      - image.jpg

I'm including the style.css file via assetic. I've installed assets with assets:install web --symlink command. I've also tried the assetic:dump command.

```css
#div {
  background: url("../images/image.jpg");
}
```

```html
{% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite'
  'assets/css/style.css'
%}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Comment: I can't test this right now, but have you tried switching the order of the arguments in the {% stylesheets %} call?

Comment: Can be helpful 
[Path of assets in CSS files in Symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9500573/path-of-assets-in-css-files-in-symfony-2)

Comment: I did come across the link you mentioned Max, I believe they were trying to keep assets in their bundles and the images in the /web dir. I reverted back to keeping my css/js/images in my AppBundle/Resources/public and including my style.css file via assetic as 'bundles/app/css/style.css' which gets my background image path to work. I guess I should report this to symfony directly?