# Set a image in Symfony2 twig

Tags: html, symfony, twig

I have the image in: src/WebBundle/img/img2.jpg

Im trying this but don´t works:

```
<img src="{{ asset('WebBundle/img/img2.jpg') }}" />
```

[Image of routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsxnR.png)

Thank you for the patience

Comment: What "does not work" means? What url is generated? Is the file in `web/bundles` directory

Comment: The image folder should be `src/WebBundle/Resources/public/img`, then you can use `{{ asset('bundles/web/img/img2.jpg') }}` afterwards. (Maybe you'll need to run `php app/console assets:install`)

Comment: Btw, relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9500573/251311

Answer (score 0):

Better to user assets.

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

In your case just change image url to avoid any url problem.